# After rewriting some of my routes using put, patch and delete my functionality doesn't work anymore and the page just refreshes. Not getting errors

Tags: php, laravel, rest

After finding out I've been writing my routes slightly wrong I decided to fix them. The routes originally looked like this:

```
Route::get('/deleteImage/{id}', 'ArtworkController@deleteImage')->name('deleteImage');
Route::get('/deleteCategory/{id}', 'CategoryController@deleteCategory')->name('deleteCategory');
Route::patch('/profile/{id}/update', 'UsersController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile');
```

And I changed them to:

```
Route::delete('/image/{id}', 'ArtworkController@deleteImage')->name('deleteImage');
Route::delete('/category/{id}', 'CategoryController@deleteCategory')->name('deleteCategory');
Route::patch('/profile/{id}', 'UsersController@updateProfile')->name('updateProfile');
```

Sadly, as soon as I changed `Route::get('/deleteImage/{id}'` to `Route::delete('/image/{id}'` something went wrong.

This is the `<a>` tag that leads to the deleteImage route:

```
<a class='placeholderDelete' href='{{ route('deleteImage', ['image_id' => $image->id]) }}'>Delete Image</a>
```

Before making the changes the image would get deleted after clicking that anchor element, however, after the changes the page just refreshes and nothing happens. The image doesn't get deleted from my database and storage.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot as I'm not getting any errors or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELETE routes need to be handled by a form that uses POST.  Normal links (anchor tags) visit a page using a GET request.  You will need to use a form.  Here is an example.

```
<form id="delete-form" class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{route('deleteImage', $image->id)}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

If you want to use a regular link to do the deletion, you could hide the form and use javascript to submit it.

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();">Delete Image</a>
```

Comment: What is the hidden input field for? Is it the equivalent of {{ method_field('delete') }} ?

Comment: Laravel looks for the value in a field called _method to determine if it should use a route method other than POST.  You also need that field for PUT/PATCH.  All forms submit using either GET or POST, and that is Laravel's way of allowing for PUT/PATCH/DELETE route methods.  And I think that it probably is equivalent to the way you said.  That might be a newer way of generating that field that I hadn't seen.

Comment: Do you think it is good idea to rework my code and start using PUT/PATCH/DELETE or should I just stick to GET/POST?

Comment: It is a good idea, but really depends on the size and scale of your project and your preferences.  If you are working with others, it's probably best to do it the "standard" way.  That way will probably be more secure and work better with future updates as well.  But if it is a small project and you prefer to do it another way, you can definitely make it work just using GET and POST.

Comment: I just wanna do things the conventional way.